# how can i acces asp.net webapplication classes another application in same solution?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

i have a webapplication in that solution i added one more project to that solution i want to acces the webapplication App_code class in my newlly added project how to acces that classes here....

Answer (score 1):

The recommended approach is to place the shared classes in a third project of type class library, and let both the web app and the second project reference the library.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `<%@ Import Namespace="EngineLibrary.BussinessLayer.CommonUtilites" %>`
on your aspx page and also use `using EngineLibrary.BussinessLayer` on your aspx.cs page.

Comment: Here EngineLibrary is my solution name and remains it's sub folders name.